# Search box: Updating page elemens directly VS creating page with results

Tags: search, results

I am asked to create a search function within a portal/dashboard.

There are two options that I have in mind.

1. Search box gives some options while searching but when clicking on search it gives a separate page with results.

[image]

2. Search box automatically updates the content within the page.

[image]

The second option is working out to be much simpler. I am wondering if this is a pattern, that for any reason I can't see now, we should not use or what I have to take into consideration.

e.g. I believe it needs to be very clear when the page shows only part of the content due to an active search.

Is this clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think option 2 is better for the user, since there's no need for more interactions with the search bar.

Algolia has this demo where you can try this feature:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/widgets/showcase/js/
[image]